# Verilog training

Tags: verilog

Alright, I am currently in a situation where knowledge of FPGAs might come in handy. I took the subject at university quite a while back then and since I didn't need it, I forgot most of it (also it was VHDL).
After reading a bit I thought that maybe Verilog would be better suited to me. Now I would like to jump-start my knowledge and therefore I would like to take part in a course. I saw that there are courses available at the Xilinx website (which in turn links to various training facilities which offer these).
The problem: I do not know if they are worth the cost. I don't mind investing some money if this saves some time in the end but if I wouldn't gain more than from an online course it's kind of useless.
Or to put this question in another direction: Do you know of any good Verilog courses around here? I don't mind them being in English.

(Around here is actually Western Austria, so basically Austria, Germany and Switzerland are ok)

Comment: [FPGA programming — where to begin?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/41528/fpga-programming-where-to-begin/)

Comment: Actually my question goes into a different direction, but great resources, though. Imho no book or online resource can be a few says with a pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Get a Xilinix ISE or some other Verilog/VHDL Simulator,
- try tutorials online to design
- construct testbenches to test the designs

Just google these tutorials/examples

**Here's a popular website with two classes**

[Complex Digital Systems - MIT OpenCoursware](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-884-complex-digital-systems-spring-2005/lecture-notes/)

[Introductory to Digital Systems Laboratory - MIT OpenCourseware](http://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/49431/6-111Spring2004/OcwWeb/Electrical-Engineering-and-Computer-Science/6-111Spring2004/CourseHome/index.htm)

Nothing yet on coursera.com, edx.org or udacity.com but I'd keep an eye on them

**Other Resources:**

[OpenCores](http://opencores.org)  (highly recommend signing up here for sophisticated projects)

[Asic-World](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/index.html)