# Beginning with programming microcontrollers

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, basic

I am a software developer (coming from Java and Javascript/web-app programming) and I'm very interested in programming microcontrollers like Arduino or Espruino. The problem is I have little to no knowledge about electronics. When it comes to circuit diagrams, etc., I have no idea what it means.

What do you recommend to get started with the basic electronics on a project level? I took a look at starter kits like the [Fritzing Creator Kit](http://fritzing.org/fritzing-creatorkit/?language=en). Would this be a good starting point? Or are there any other good starting point like a Youtube channel, blog, any good website...?

Comment: start with PIC or ATMEL 8bit /16 bit microcontroller...follow the course called "electronic interface " in edx.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well that depends on what family of microcontroller you want to work. You definitely need development board/ starter kits to begin microcontroller programming. If you want to go for PIC MCUs, [**Explorer 16 board**](http://picmania.garcia-cuervo.net/images/explorer-16_microchip_00.jpg) are best or you can go for other [**development**](http://advetech.in/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/PIC-Development-Board1.jpg) boards for PIC.

If you want to start with AVR MCUs, then purchase an AVR development board.

[**Arduino Uno**](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/38/Arduino_Uno_-_R3.jpg) is also a good starter kit to start your programming. There are many tutorials available online.

If you don't want to purchase any starter kit and want to simulate your design in [**Proteus Simulator**](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=proteus%20simulator), then this [**blog**](http://embeddedmastrex.blogspot.in/) can you help you.!

You probably need books to understand microcontroller's & their programming. For AVR read [**this**](http://www.microdigitaled.com/AVR/AVR_books.htm) & for PIC go for [**this**](http://www.microdigitaled.com/PIC/PIC_books.htm) and for any [**other MCU**](http://microdigitaled.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There are many online sources available. I suggest you look at the MOOC platforms [edx.org](http://www.edx.org) and [coursera.org](http://www.coursera.org). Below is list of suggested coursers ordered from beginner to advance.

- [Electronic Interfaces: Bridging the Physical and Digital Worlds from University of California at Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/electronic-interfaces-bridging-physical-uc-berkeleyx-ee40lx-0)
- [Circuits and Electronics from Massachusetts Institute of Technology](https://www.edx.org/course/circuits-electronics-mitx-6-002x-0)
- [Embedded Systems - Shape The World from University of Texas at Austin](https://www.edx.org/course/embedded-systems-shape-world-utaustinx-ut-6-02x)
- [Cyber-Physical Systems from University of California at Berkeley](https://www.edx.org/course/cyber-physical-systems-uc-berkeleyx-eecs149-1x)
- [The Hardware/Software Interface from University of Washington](https://www.coursera.org/course/hwswinterface)

The above list is a short list of suggested free online coursers. The cost for following one or two of these courses can be managed under US $100. This should get you started.

---

**References:**

- [How can I get started with electronic engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/180512/how-can-i-get-started-with-electronic-engineering)
- [EEVBlog](http://www.eevblog.com/)
- [Verilog training](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/76056/verilog-training/76066#76066)

Answer (score 0):

I for one am using the books Make: Electronics, Electronics for Dummies, and Electronics all in one for Dummies. I am learning about circuits that way. I am just a beginner hobbyist though so I don't know any better.

By the way, I also have the Arduino Uno Starter Kit which comes with a project book and I think it's a good start if you want to start learning about Arduino directly.

But like I said, I'm a total beginner, so take my answer with a sack of salt.

Answer (score 0):

*The 8051 Microcontroller and Embedded Systems Using Assembly and C (English) 2nd Edition* by *Muhammad Ali Mazidi*

is very good book to start with.It explains Microcontroller and its application with **Assembly** and **Embedded C** in very simplified and detailed manner..

Some other book which I would recommend ...

- *Embedded Systems Design* by *Arnold S. Berger*
- *The Art of Designing Embedded Systems*

Comment: How can something be both "very simplified and detailed manner"... I wonder.

Comment: You can download that book here: https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAAahUKEwjLoN2i4t_IAhXDQhQKHUwsDNg&url=http%3A%2F%2Fjsjyl.chd.edu.cn%2FThe_8051_Microcontroller_and_Embedded_Systems_Using_Assembly_and_C.pdf&usg=AFQjCNF90Q39ThgQ10lbyQp_Mn8wyJ3XjQ&sig2=iXrJLl9sC68RWRMVy52JUA&cad=rja and I would have thought that any book that has a pdf is probably not up to date or very good. Do you see the problem in recommending books - it's just an opinion and this site is really not about opinions.

Comment: @Andy aka: you can download many books from Chinese sites... which probably don't give two renminbi about copyright.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff yes I am aware of that.

Comment: @Andy aka: The edu.cn link you gave (via google redirect) is a bit of bait-and-switch: only the cover is from that book... the rest is a bunch of slides by someone else... although it seems he used the book as textbook for those course slides.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff good job this question has been closed down then!